# At least one object must implement IComparable, IComparable is implemented

Tags: c#, sorting

First of, I know this question has been asked multiple times but the solution those offer are not helping me.

I have the following `Classes`:

```
public class PartType : IComparable<PartType>
{
    public int CompareTo(PartType other)
    {
        return this.Type.CompareTo(other.Type);
    }

    // Some code

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The above class is used in the class below.

```
public class Part : IComparable<Part>
{
    public int CompareTo(Part other)
    {
        return this.Material.CompareTo(other.Material);
    }

    public string Material { get; set; }
    public PartType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have a `ObservableCollection<PartType>` I can sort without any problems on `string Type` (don't need to be able to do anything else).

My other `ObservableCollection<Part>` I can sort on `string Material` but NOT on `PartType Type` (sorry for the confusion by using the word Type twice).

Comment: Seriously consider renaming your `Type` member due to possible naming collision with `System.Type`

Comment: @Krowi - It is not clear what you are asking. Your post does not contain a question.

Comment: @decPL: what kind of naming collision are you referring to? Even a property like `PartType PartType` is fine even if it's "colliding" directly with the type.

Comment: @Krowi What's not working? Check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2RVfDt. It seems to work.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `Type` is a name of an often-used (no pun intended) type in .Net. I don't believe it is a good name of a class' member, just as I would avoid `String`, `Int32`, even though all of those would compile.

Comment: @decPL: but it's not a type but  a property-name. That's a great difference.

Comment: @decPL `public string Name { get; set; }` would certainly make more sense because it's the PartType's Name.  Still waiting for OP to clarify what the question is exactly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter so would be `public int String`, but I believe it diminishes readability, so I'd advise anyone to avoid such a naming scheme; YMMV

Comment: @decPL: why would you want to  give   a property wich  returns an `int` the name `String`? That's pointless.  But for example: `class Background { Color Color { get; set; }
}`. So now if you have an instance you can write: `deskTop.BackGround.Color = Color.Green`. No conflict and very readable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter apples and oranges IMHO - in your example, your property has the same type as it's name; in my (and OP's) the member name might suggest a completely different type than it really is, which is counterintuitive if you look at some usage, until you navigate to definition.

Comment: And, `part.Type.Type` is somewhat awkward.

Comment: @decPL: so if there is somewhere already a type `Date` in the framework or in another library i should never use a property `Date` in one of my classes? **Edit** Acc. to the duplicate `Type`s you're right. One of them should be renamed, but not because there is already `System.Type`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Would you expect to use that type relatively commonly in your code? Is there a chance that there are tons of code samples where this type is used? Do we have `GetDate()` methods throughout .Net CTS that returns said `Date` class? Does any common class (don't know, say System.Object) implement such a method? Because if the answer to all is 'hell, yes' - I would consider avoiding using it as a name of your property. Otherwise just use common sense.

Comment: @decPL: There's nothing bad in providing a property `Date`(f.e. in a class `Wedding`, it's clear and safe to write `myWedding.Date`) even if `Object` would have a method `GetDate` and there is a commonly used class `Date`.   But let us stop this discussion, it's opinion-based (where is the chat for comments?).

Comment: Despite what the average dev might think, 90% of what can be said about best coding practices/standards is opinion-based, so no argument here :) Agree to disagree I guess, have a lovely day; btw - was also wondering what happened to the 'move to chat' link...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IComparable` is not implemented, only `IComparable<T>`...

In your case, the method you use to sort the `ObservableCollection<T>` seems to expect this non-generic interface to be implemented. (you didn't state how you sort!).

If you are using the [`System.Linq.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) extension, it should work with only the generic interface, as [Comparer.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/azhsac5f(v=vs.110).aspx) has an internal Fallback.

You should always implement generic and non-generic interfaces for your classes in order to support common behaviour that is independent of whether the caller "understands" generics or not.

Comment: So why do I need to implement both? Is it cause of some old non generic classes?